# formatar retorno json com javascript

Tags: jquery, json

tenho o seguinte codigo

```
function functionCLick(name) {  
   $.getJSON('livros.json', function(data){
       $.each(data, function(i, item){
            if(item.name == name){
                $("#conteudo").html("<p>"+item.chapters+"</p>");
            }
       });
    });
 }
```

segue uma parte do json

```
[
    {
        "abbrev": "hob", 
        "chapters": [
            [
                "exemplo1.",
                "exemplo2.",
                "exemplo3."

            ],
            [
                "exemplo4.",
                "exemplo5.",
                "exemplo6."
            ] 
        ],
        "name": "hoobit"
    },
]
```

a minha duvida é o seguinte queria saber se tem como formatar a saída. A minha saída no navegador é a seguinte ele insere no html todo o conteúdo que esta em **chapters** inclusive ele também mostra as **virgulas** de final de linha do json **exemplo:** exemplo1.,exemplo2.,exemplo3.,exemplo4.,exemplo5.,exemplo6.
ele me retorna as virgulas que estão no final de cada linha do **chapters** do json. Pensei em remover todas as virgulas com o jquery mas pensando, no texto pode ter alguma virgula que não pode ser removida. E outra duvida consigo quebrar os **chapters**

Comment: Mas você queria que ficasse cada chapter num `<p>` diferente ?

Comment: Vc pode utilizar regex para retirar as vírgulas do final do texto e deixar qualquer outra vírgula que possa vir no mesmo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O `item.chapters` está retornando as duas arrays, logo virão separadas por vírgulas, inclusive os valores de cada uma. O que você precisa fazer é um outro `.each` para retornar as subarrays e seus valores dentro de cada parágrafo:

> Coloquei uma vírgula no `exemplo1` e `exemplo5` para mostrar que as
>   vírgulas dentro dos valores não são afetadas.

```js
var data = [
    {
        "abbrev": "hob", 
        "chapters": [
            [
                "exemplo1,.",
                "exemplo2.",
                "exemplo3."

            ],
            [
                "exemplo4.",
                "exemplo5,.",
                "exemplo6."
            ] 
        ],
        "name": "hoobit"
    },
]
var name = "hoobit";
var chaps = ''; //  cria a variável vazia onde será armazenado o HTML
$.each(data, function(i, item){
   if(item.name == name){
      $.each(item.chapters, function(idx){
         $.each(item.chapters[idx], function(c, v){
            $("#conteudo").append("<p>"+v+"</p>");
         });
      });
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="conteudo"></div>
```

Comment: agora deu certo, obrigado pela dica, e uma outra pergunta como eu colocaria cada chapter em um paragrafo diferente porque eles ficam todos juntos.

Comment: O que seria um parágrafo? isso `[
                "exemplo1.",
                "exemplo2.",
                "exemplo3."

            ],` tudo ou cada item?

Comment: o paragrafo seria isso [ "exemplo1.", "exemplo2.", "exemplo3." ] e tambem quebrar a linha quando tiver o ponto final

Comment: Seria `<p>exemplo1.</p>` etc.. ou `<p>exemplo1. exemplo2. exemplo3.</p>`?

Comment: seria assim <p>exemplo1.</p>etc... o paragrafo ira ate o final de cada linha do json cada linha deve ficar em um <p> diferente e quando entrar em outro chapter que seria do exemplo 4 ao 6 ele ira ter um titulo e começar os exemplos de 4 a 6

Comment: Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: muito obrigado, agora deu certinho como eu queria